# Problems with moving and coying files in NERDTree

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I'm trying to learn Vim and have problems with copying/moving files using NERDTree.
For example:
I have two folders on my Desktop

> FolderA
>
> FolderB
>
> some_file.txt

And i want to move some_file.txt to FolderA.
I press "m" for NERDTree menu and another "m" to move and I get this path:

> Enter the new path for the node:
> /home/user1/Desktop/some_file.txt

and I do

> /home/user1/Desktop/some_file.txt FolderA

and what I get is just renamed file

> "some_file.txt FolderA"
> and file is not moved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "new path" is not what you want, to put the `some_file.txt` inside `FolderA` try this

```
Enter the new path for the node:
/home/user1/Desktop/FolderA/some_file.txt
```